# Why am I getting an "a.exe has stopped working" error on Visual Studio Code for my linked list program?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list, undefined-behavior, null-pointer

I'm playing around with a linked list, and I'm getting an error when I try to print out the value of the tail and the address of the next value:

```
struct Node {
    int n;
    Node *next;
};

class LinkedList {
    public:
        Node *head = NULL;
        Node *tail = NULL;
};

int main() {
    LinkedList L;
    L.head = NULL;
    L.tail = NULL;

    Node *new_node = new Node();
    new_node->n = 1;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    
    L.tail->next = new_node;
    L.tail = new_node;

    cout << L.tail << endl;
    cout << L.tail->next << endl;
}
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: PSA: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: `L.tail->next` is set null, so you're asking it to print an invalid `Node` pointer.

Comment: `L.tail->next = new_node;` is dereferencing a null pointer. I would expect this to go splat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these statements:

```
L.tail = NULL;
//...
L.tail->next = new_node;
```

You are trying to use a null pointer to access memory. That invokes *undefined behavior*.

---

Also, these assignments:

```
LinkedList L;
L.head = NULL;
L.tail = NULL;
```

are redundant, due to the class's default initialization of its members:

```
class LinkedList {
    public:
        Node *head = NULL;
        Node *tail = NULL;
};
```